# Replacing a special character in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

How do we replace a special character in Power BI on query editor?

This is my data :

> Corresponding Business Objects - PFMC

But it appears as

> Corresponding Business Objects � PFMC

A question mark (?) with a 4 sided quadruple surrounded next to it. I am not able to use replace values. I copied in the � and tried to replace it with "-" but it is not working.

How can we fix this.

Comment: Have you tried `Text.Clean`?

Comment: @AlexisOlson No, But that would remove and not replace right ?

Comment: Hmm. It looks like it doesn't do either. Let me try something else.

Comment: Using Replace Values works for me. What trouble are you having with it?

Comment: @AlexisOlson That worked. My mistake - I was trying with Match Entire Characters. Can you please put that as an answer ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the following work for me:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Previous Step","�","-",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"ColumnName"})

= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Previous Step",Character.FromNumber(65533),"-",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"ColumnName"})
```

The first line was generated from the Transform > Replace Values tool:

[image]